# Is it ok to call a Web API to log user activity?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

My application consists of two separate projects - UI project (AngularJS) and a Web API project (ASP.NET).

I want to log all user activity such as button clicks, user logins etc.

Currently I am using factories in Angular to consume the API like below:

```
var urlBase = 'http://localhost:8298/user';

userDataFactory.insertUser = function (user) {
    return $http.post(urlBase + '/create', user);
};
```

Now I want to log these actions to a database with a stored procedure. But these questions are posing over me.

Is it ok to replicate the above but call a Log API that passes the user activity to the stored procedure?

Should I worry about authorizing the log creation? Otherwise anyone could log activity by calling the route?

Even if authorization is required, a user could continue to call the Log API at their will and populate it with whatever data they wish.

Are there any alternatives?

Comment: You should do logging in the code of the original call. You shouldn't open your logging up to a potential external attack-- I could easily use javascript and the browser's developer tools to do whatever I want with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are merely setting up auditing, you should do it all server side, so there is no chance someone subverts your system.

If you must do this client side, create a routine to handle the call to the service. And, yes, I would have some type of authentication, so nobody can subvert your activity. But even client side script can be tracked on the server side if there is a call to the server for information, so you still do not need to log from the client side where someone can get your script and subvert your intentions.

Could you duplicate the routine? Sure, but why? If you must do this client side add a call to a "logging routine". Or, better yet, in the call to create the user, log the access on the server side.